# URL Concatenate in report builder

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0

In Report Builder I want to build a Action URL that requires concatenation.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
="https://synergy.pumpnseal.com/enterprise/docs/WflRequest.aspx?Mode=1&ID=%" + Fields!id.Value + "%7d&BCAction=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
="https://synergy.pumpnseal.com/enterprise/docs/WflRequest.aspx?Mode=1&ID=%" & cstr(Fields!id.Value) & "%7d&BCAction=1"
```

I'm not sure if there's any real difference in this instance between `+` and `&`, but I always use `&` to be explicit that I mean concatenate and not add.

Comment: Thanks @BishNaboB but no success

Comment: @GBP what does it show in the browser when you access it? Does the URL look malformed?